# Cannot use "description" keyword with NSObject

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

I am parsing a json and use this `NSObject` class to access values, but I cant use "description" keyword to match the key "description" in json data. The compiler says "description is a inner property in `NSObject`".

```
class JsonDetails: NSObject {

    var id: NSNumber?
    var title: String?
    var description: String?
    var address: String?
    var postcode: String?
    var phoneNumber: String?
    var latitude: String?
    var longitude: String?
    var image: [Img]?

    class Img: NSObject {
        var small: String?
        var medium: String?
        var large: String?
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you really need inheritance from `NSObject`? And don't use optionals carelessly and globally as a replacement for an initializer.

Comment: I am new to ios and I find this from a tutorial, I dont know any other way to do this.

Comment: var dataCategories = [JsonDetails]()
                    
                    for dict in (json?["data"] as! [[String:AnyObject]]) {
                        
                        
                        
                        let dataCategory = JsonDetails()
                        dataCategory.setValuesForKeys(dict)
                        dataCategories.append(dataCategory)
                       
                        
                    }.    //this is the json code

Comment: In normal case you don't need inheritance from `NSObject` in iOS. You need it for Objective-C compatibility or if you are going to use KVC. Just delete `NSObject` and you can use `description` without error.

Comment: PS: `setValuesForKeys` is indeed a KVC method which requires `NSObject`. But there are also (more suitable) native Swift solutions.

Comment: Thank you very much, i have removed NSObject and then I cant acess "setValuesForKeys" method. now Im writing a class takes dictionary as @powerj1984 says

Comment: thank you sir, I will look for more suitable solutions

Answer (score 0):

Because "description" is already an inherited method of NSObject you cannot have a var of the same name. Renaming your var to 'desc' is an option though.

Comment: I tried that, then I got a unknown key exception, I think json "description" key must have to match with NS objects variable name

Comment: Show your code which generates the exception? If you have control of the web service, and it makes sense to do so, you could rename it from description to something else at that level as well.

Comment: let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? AnyObject
                    
                    var dataCategories = [JsonDetails]()
                    
                    for dict in (json?["data"] as! [[String:AnyObject]]) {
                        
                        
                        
                        let dataCategory = JsonDetails()
                        dataCategory.setValuesForKeys(dict)
                        dataCategories.append(dataCategory)
                       
                        
          }

Comment: It's breaking at setValuesForKeys: your incoming object has a key "description" and your JsonDetails does not, when it tries setting "description" on the JsonDetails object an exception is thrown. A much better practice here would be to write an init method for your class that takes a dictionary and set the values yourself instead of using setValuesForKeys. Then init your objects with the dictionaries.

Also, as @vadian mentioned it doesn't look like there is a good reason for your class to subclass NSObject here (does it need to interop with ObjC?)

Comment: A major reason of using Swift over ObjC is type safety and methods like setValuesForKeys go against that philosophy. Having that method isn't a good reason to subclass NSObject.

Comment: thank you very much for your advices and help, I will follow them.. It doesnt need to intelop with objC..I used NSObject because  then I can ue setValuesForKeys method.